# Error Statement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

> No suitable method found for setDate(int,java.util.Date) method
>   PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date,Calendar) is not
>   applicable

```
public void update (Pasien dp) {
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
PreparedStatement statement = null;
try {
    statement =  connection.prepareStatement(update);

    statement.setString(1, dp.getId_pemeriksaan());
    statement.setString(2,dp.getNama());
    statement.setString(3,dp.getAlamat());
    statement.setString(4,dp.getUmur());
    statement.setString(5,dp.getJenis_kelamin());
    statement.setString(6,dp.getGolongan_darah());
    statement.setString(7,dp.getSpesimen());
    statement.setString(8,dp.getPengirim());
    statement.setString(9,dp.getPemeriksaan());
    statement.setDate(10, dp.getTanggal()df.format(getTanggal));
    statement.setString(11, dp.getNo_rekam_medik());
    statement.executeUpdate();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println("error karena" +ex.getMessage());
}finally{
    try {
        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("error karena" +ex.getMessage());
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This line of code is suspicious:

```
statement.setDate(10, dp.getTanggal()df.format(getTanggal));
```

Should, perhaps, be: `statement.setDate(10, df.parse(dp.getTanggal()));`

(if `dp.getTanggal()` method is a `String`).

---

Obviously you haven't checked the `PreparedStatement.setDate()` method.

The method has the following signature:

```
void setDate(int parameterIndex, java.sql.Date x) throws SQLException;
```

It's not a `java.util.Date` but a `java.sql.Date` object.

If you want to use `Calendar` then:

```
void setDate(int parameterIndex, java.sql.Date x, Calendar cal) throws SQLException;
```

is the one to call. Obviously, this still requires `java.sql.Date` object.

---

To convert a `java.util.Date` to a `java.sql.Date`, you can do this:

```
java.util.Date date = df.parse(...);
java.sql.Date = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception says the exact error.

> No suitable method found for setDate(int,java.util.Date) method
>   PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date,Calendar) is not
>   applicable]

In your src the below line

```
dp.getTanggal()df.format(getTanggal)
```

is returning `java.util.Date`. But the `PreparedStatement.setDate()` method expects `java.sql.Date`

Answer (score 0):

```
statement.setDate(10, dp.getTanggal()df.format(getTanggal));
```

you have forgot to put `comma(,)`. :)

But the interesting part is `DateFormat#format` returns a formatted `String` representation of Date. Which need to pass it trough `setString` method.